# Any c++ program doesn't output anything

Tags: c++, console

Using Code::Blocks, tried other IDEs,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Even this code doesn't work. I know something's wrong with my environment, becouse I've tried running my program from the console, also, it works on other computers. *Using: Windows 7, 64bit*

Comment: You are going to have to share more information than that with us.

Comment: What information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the antivirus program Avast hanging when it does the scan for new exe launches. We upgraded our Avast and it fixed the problem for us . Another user yesterday posted that he changed his Avast "Deepscreen" setting. Do you have Avast ? If so please try updating it and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Been stuck for week or so, finally - the solution! Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have messed something while installing code:: blocks.
Revisit that site and click downloads
Now, when you downloaded previously, which version of code blocks you downloaded? Was it plain code:: blocks or code:: blocks with MingGW?
Remember, you have to select Code:: blocks with MinGW. This is a set of ide+compiler. The other one is just plain ide.
In code blocks select new project> console application>c++ next next...
Then in main.cpp, write your code and press f9 to compile and run

Comment: I think i downloaded version with MingGW, but I'll try

Comment: Did you follow all steps of creating a project I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, uninstalled the old one, downloaded version with MingGW, "new project> console application>c++ next next... Then in main.cpp, write your code and press f9 to compile and run"

Comment: No, no output in the console, but compiles okay :(

Answer (score 0):

Download codeblocks-13.12mingw from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe) and again try.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, compiles okay, runs, and displays nothing

Comment: This may occur for antivirus also. Please disable the antivirus and try.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by adding "stdafx.h".
VS-2015 issued this warning to me long ago.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
>   header.